# Why does genexp(generator expression) is called genexp? not iterexp?

Tags: python, python-internals

A generator is a special kind of iterator, and it has some methods that an normal iterator doesn't have such as **send()**, **close()**... etc.
One can get a generator by using a genexp like below:

```
g=(i for i in range(3))
```

the type of g will be a generator.
But it seems weird to me that **g** is a generator because **g.send** will do nothing since g isn't returned by a function with **yield** keyword, and there would be no chance for one to catch the value passed by send method(not sure this is right), I don't see a reason that **g** needs to be a generator instead of a more generalize type:iterator.

Comment: Can you link to the sources where the claims are stated?

Comment: what claims? the content are all stated by myself if i were wrong please correct me tks!

Comment: I mean, like to the reference material please. :-)

Comment: @Tobias - I can't figure out what you want either.

Comment: Link to the language specification where it says: "These things are called called so-and-so."

Comment: @tdelaney not quite understanding what you mean by "A generator is an iterable sequence"

Comment: I've tested that isinstance(g,abc.Iterator) returns True, or it doesn't mean anything?

Comment: Oops, you are right! I had `range` on the brain, not `(i for i in range(3))`. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some misunderstanding about definitions:

1. *Iterable* is an object that implements `__iter__`. Also `__iter__` is expected to return an iterator.
2. *Iterator* is an object that implements `next`.
3. *Generator function* is a function with `yield` keyword.
4. *Generator object* is an object returned by a generator function. Every generator object is an iterator as well.
5. *Generator expression* is a generator version of list comprehension. The result of generator expression is also called a *generator object* or simply a *generator*.

Some authors use general *generator* name in one of the meanings above. You have to know the context to truely understand what they are refering to. But since all those objects are closely tied there's no real problem with it.

It's always hard to answer questions "why is it like that?" when asking about naming conventions. Unless you ask the original creators its almost impossible to provide a satisfactory answer. For example it might simply be an effect of evolution and as we all know evolution does introduce errors. But here's my guess:

Both generator expressions and generator functions produce the same type of object. Now why do they produce the same object? That's probably because it was the easiest way to implement it like that under the hood. That might be the motivation.

Also note that there's a noticable difference between iterators and generator expressions: you can use `yield` keyword in generator expressions. Even though it is not really useful and introduces lots of confusion, the behaviour is not intuitive at all.

Resources:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: yeah, I understand the difference between each of these, my question is that if the object returned by genexp can do nothing with the send method, what's the meaning of having this method?

Comment: @LtChang As you've noted it is impossible to put a code inside a generator expression that accepts external data (even though you actually can use `yield` inside generator expression). So the function does nothing. There is no meaning. But it's not really an issue. It's like when you have a subclass of some class with a trivialy defined method.

Comment: Again: the question "why it was designed like this?" is beyond my capabilities. I assume you'd have to ask the authors.

Comment: If anybody has the time, it might be worth looking into the PEPs that introduced these features for the motivation and design choices.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function is restricted in certain ways (no control structures, no doc string) but creates a real function object. You might ask in the same way, why does a lambda function have a `__doc__` attribute that returns `None`, instead of `AttributeError`, since no lambda function could possibly have a doc string?

A subtype of a certain kind of value should be [substitutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for values of the base type. (And special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.)

```
>>> def g(): yield
>>> type(g())
<class 'generator'>
>>> h = (i for i in [1,2,3])
>>> type(h)
<class 'generator'>
```

A generator expression looks like a list comprehension syntactically, but the value produced has the type *generator iterator*, and so should be usable in the same way as one produced using `yield` in a generator function. In this case, calling `.send(foo)` should do nothing except advance the function body.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. The thing produced by a genexp has a `send` because it's a generator, but the question seems to be asking why the value is a generator at all if it doesn't have any use for `send`. This answer doesn't say anything about why genexps were designed to create generators.

Answer (score 0):

While genexps don't need and can't benefit from `send` functionality, they were introduced before `send` was a thing. Back then, generators had no additional API features over generic iterators.

Even if `send` had come first, it would probably have complicated the language more to document and implement another iterator type for genexps to evaluate to than to reuse the generator design.